# where can i find simple customizable javascript/jquery based forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a good looking form for the home page to get users signed up for beta access. I would like the form to pre-fill a field with an indicator e.g. "email address" but then go blank and get highlighted when a user clicks to fill in his email.

Rather than design one, I would greatly appreciate some free/cheap resources on the web that allow for pretty simple insertion of javascript/html code along with nice button images if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out 55 jQuery form Plugins to download and use. Go thru them and see which ones works for you.
http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/55-jquery-form-plugins-to-download-and-use/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/V5ZgJ/)? No jQuery, JS, or Plugin required. [See HTML5 Restrictions](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html). There are compatibility issues with IE and Android Browsers.

```
<input id='email' name='email' placeholder='Enter Your Email Address'>
```

---

```
IE  FIREFOX SAFARI  CHROME  OPERA   IPHONE  ANDROID
-    3.7+    4.0+    4.0+    11.0+   4.0+    -
```

Answer (score 0):

The effect you mention is called `placeholder` it works natively in `HTML5` but as you will probably want cross plataform support there are many jQuery plug ins for that, Check:

http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/

http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html